# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Symbol

Tags: python

```
from sympy import *

t6,a,b,c = symbols ('t6,a,b,c')
result=solve([(a*cos(t6))+(b*sin(t6))+c],[t6])
cs=[(a,-26.468147779101194),(b,4.395890741437306),(c,19.920476269921963)]

t6 = result[t6].subs(cs)
```

trying to solve an equation
i guess it is because it has two results
because it works fine on simplier equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `list` (i.e., `[]`) inside `solve()`

```
t6,a,b,c = symbols('t6,a,b,c')
result=solve((a*cos(t6))+(b*sin(t6))+c, t6)
cs=[(a,-26.468147779101194),(b,4.395890741437306),(c,19.920476269921963)]

# solve for t6
for i in range(len(result)):
    t6 = result[i].subs(cs)
    print(t6)
```

output:

```
0.569494943945226
-0.898655036471938
```